# Docker + WSL2 in a Windows 2022 server

Tags: windows, docker, blazor, wsl-2

Can I run docker in wsl2 on a Windows 2022 server?
It is a development server and I want to run my Blazor application in a Docker container but Docker Desktop cannot be installed on it.
So I do not know how to creat an image on Windows without installed Docker Desktom. I read the Docker Engine is available olnly on Linux.
Maybe I will copy the source code and Docker file into the Linux and I build it there but I do not know if it is a valid idea.
This is my problem.

I tried to install Docker Desktop on Windows server but they said it is not a good idea and I also got errors.

Comment: `they said it is not a good idea and I also got errors.` who's they and what errors did you get? Docker and WSL is what almost everyone uses on Windows. Even SQL Server only publishes Linux images

Comment: It is virtualized Windows server and they said it is not a good idea to run another virtualization in it. I'm just getting to know Docker, so I don't have any experience with it.